# Style SnackBar in theme app

Tags: android, styles, material-components, material-components-android, android-snackbar

I need help. How can I change the design of the text in snackbar in styles app?  The change in the code does not interest me. I found the following code. But it is not working for me. Why is that?  My theme is derived from @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". I would be very grateful for the help.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar.Message" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FEFEFE</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar.Action" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FEFEFE</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: **using C# xamarin or Java, you can try this** [Answer to change the background color of snackbar in Xamarin C# Or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63366778/7404931)

Answer (score 45):

With the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md) you can **globally** change the snackbar style in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <!-- Style to use for Snackbars in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar</item>
    <!-- Style to use for action button within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar</item>
    <!-- Style to use for message text within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView</item>
    ....
</style>
```

**Note**:

- `snackbarStyle` and `snackbarButtonStyle` require the version **`1.1.0`**
- `snackbarTextViewStyle` requires the version **`1.2.0`**.

For example:

```
  <style name="snackbar_style" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">32dp</item>
  </style>

  <style name="snackbar_button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
      <item name="backgroundTint">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="snackbar_text" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

It is just an example how to change also the parent style for the action button. You can use for example a standard `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`:

```
  <style name="snackbar_button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
      <item name="backgroundTint">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>
```

To change the **background color** of the `SnackBar` you can use:

```
<style name="snackbar_style" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <!-- using backgroundTint the alpha layer is ignored -->
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Or if you prefer:

```
   <style name="MySnackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/snackbar_overlay</item>
        <!-- If you want to avoid the alpha level for the color that is overlaid on top of the background color-->
        <item name="backgroundOverlayColorAlpha">1.0</item>
    </style>
    <style name="snackbar_overlay">
        <item name="colorOnSurface">....</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Wonderful!!. Finally styling snackbar completly at theme level. Playing around with the above suggestion, I found that we can specify a custom background shape/color in the snack bar style.  <style name="snackbar_style" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar”>  <item name="android:layout_margin">32dp</item>  **<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_snackbar</item>  <item name="backgroundTint”>@color/snackbarBackgroundColor</item>**  <item name="animationMode">slide</item>  </style>

Comment: when applying snackbar_button, the color is indeed changed. But the color is slightly more bright, and checking it with a color picker shows that the color is not exactly the chosen color.

Answer (score 23):

you need this: `tools:override="true"`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar.Message" parent="android:TextAppearance" tools:override="true">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is the only way to style it in XML as of right now. There's a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223344) in to allow styling it properly.

Answer (score 13):

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/materialdoc/materialdoc-web/blob/master/docs/components/snackbars-and-toasts.md) for more information:

// create instance

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);
```

// set action button color

```
snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo));
```

// get snackbar view

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
```

// change snackbar text color

```
int snackbarTextId = android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text;
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarView.findViewById(snackbarTextId);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo));
```

// change snackbar background

```
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Comment: If you are using the new material components use
com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text
instead of android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [shadowsheep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484438/2914140) I wrote these styles with `Material Components`. I also removed margins. You can compile his [app](https://github.com/shadowsheep1/android-snackbar-theming) to research `Snackbar`.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Snackbar -->
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MaterialSnackbarTheme</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/MaterialSnackbarTextButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/MaterialSnackbarTextViewTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialSnackbarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <!-- <item name="backgroundTint">#00cc77</item>-->
    <!-- <item name="android:background">@drawable/snackbar_background</item>-->
    <item name="android:background">#00cc77</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="actionTextColorAlpha">1.0</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialSnackbarTextButtonTheme" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
    <item name="backgroundTint">#7777ff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialSnackbarTextViewTheme" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:alpha">1.0</item>
</style>
```

Where drawable/snackbar_background.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid android:color="#00cc77" />
</shape>
```

Don't forget to remove from `Snackbar.make()`, if you have added:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bg_color))
setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button_color))
```

Unlike `AlertDialog`, `Snackbar` holds `snackbarButtonStyle` and `snackbarTextViewStyle` settings inside `AppTheme` (that's strange because yesterday they worked well inside `MaterialSnackbarTheme`).

As @StayCool said in comments, `Snackbar` currently uses transparency for background and text color (alpha = 0.5 - 0.6). Also they added round corners and margins. To remove background transparency, use either `<item name="actionTextColorAlpha">1.0</item>` or drawable/snackbar_background.xml. You can see his [variant](https://pastebin.com/xVc2PrAi).

[image]

Comment: How can I override primary/accent colors for snackbar only? I trie your solution but <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> just don't work for button textColor. Maybe ThemeOverlay?

Comment: @StayCool, I have just checked my example, these two colors don't affect SnackBar. I changed them and nothing has changed. Can you ask a question in SO?

Comment: @StayCool, that's strange. I changed button color in <item name="android:textColor"> and it applied.

Comment: @StayCool, did you set `<item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/MaterialSnackbarTextButtonTheme</item>` in the `AppTheme`?

Comment: yes, I did. [my snackbar styles](https://pastebin.com/xVc2PrAi) now contain a lot of attributes, because their parent styles contained selectors that used alpha 0.6 and some other things that was not obvious. i.e. when I set snackbar's button textColor to solid red, i ended up with 0.6 red. It was so confusing. Now I have succesfully changed background of snackbar with that: android:background, I set it to drawable gradient =) Also, I user material theme overlay to override colorPrimary user for button Stroke color.

Comment: @StayCool, yes, MDC Snackbar's background is partially transparent, so I set drawable/snackbar_background.xml. Good that you figured out all those bugs and features of MDC. :)

Comment: hmmm... if that was planned by material design maybe we don't wanna change that transparency? ^^ I was just confused because button's text was opaque, and snackbar's text wasn't

Comment: @StayCool, you are right! Transparency is often not needed, at least, if we didn't want. They changed this behaviour. I will test your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @StayCool About the background color it is not correct. The background color is based on the `colorOnSurface` You can override the color using  `<item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/...</item>` in your style (you can check my answer above). Using the `backgroundTint` the alpha layer is ignored. In any case you can override it using the attr `backgroundOverlayColorAlpha`. Finally you should avoid to use `android:background`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti but I can't use gradient background for snackbar with backgroundOverlayColorAlpha or overriding colorOnSurface for my snackBarStyle?

Comment: @StayCool With backgroundOverlayColorAlpha and backgroundTint you can't use gradient (as all the other components in material components library).

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, and as I see, there is no other way to set drawable gradient for a snackbar, except android:background

Comment: @StayCool currently it is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I digged into Snackbar sources and here's what I found
Snackbar background consists of 2 layers: base and overlay, which colors are mixing.

In order to specify these colors, just add to your Theme 2 parameters:

*colorSurface* - background color, default = 0xFFFFFFFF

*colorOnSurface* - overlay, default = 0xFF000000

So in a default case, with applied 0.8 alpha by default, a color we get is 0xFF333333, which is in a middle between white and black.

Have fun mixing and styling your Snackbar :)

Comment: can you show what you mean?  Do you add these to the snackbar themes.  Please show some code.