# How to change background color of the snackbar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-dialogfragment, android-snackbar

I am showing `snackbar` in a `DialogFragment` within the positive touch of the alert dialog. Here is my code snippet:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please enter customer name", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null);
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
sbView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
snackbar.show();
```

[image: As you can see my snackbars background color is showing white color]

I am passing the view of the `DialogFragment` to the snackbar. I want the background color to be black. How can I do this? I am returning the `alertDialog` in the `DialogFragment`. And the theme I am setting to the dialog as follow's:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Although I am setting the background color to white for the dialog, it should override by setting the background color to the *snackbar*.

Comment: [http://www.technotalkative.com/part-3-styling-snackbar/](http://www.technotalkative.com/part-3-styling-snackbar/)

Comment: tried that already not helping me...i am calling snack bar from the dialog fragment + alertDialog in it and i am passing positive button click view to the snackbar

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Try setting background color like this:

```
sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.BLACK));
```

It will work 100% !

Comment: you may need to do `snackBarView.getView().setBackgrondColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.BLACK));`

Comment: If you found this page from Google and above solution didn't work for you, you may need to try this one instead: `sbView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLACK))`

Comment: @modu Note that `getResources#getColor` has been deprecated since API level 23 (Marshmallow) and `ContextCompat#getColor` should be used instead.

Answer (score 94):

you can do it like this

```
Snackbar snackbar;
snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);
TextView textView = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(textColor);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: as u can see i did exactly same thing but it not showing in black color

Comment: i have use the same in one of my project, try to display it in activity for testing, may be it is not working due to dialog

Comment: ya its working on activity but i want it on the dialog fragment.

Comment: i think it is because of your view that you are passing to it

Answer (score 38):

As none of the other answers provided a custom style override (that I consider one of the safest update way to do that) I post here my solution.

I post a solution that already address the new `AndroidX` (`support design 28`) theme.

Provided that your application use a custom them called `MyAppTheme` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplicationName"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

Create (if you haven't already) `values/style.xml` file overriding the theme used by your application:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myColorAccent</item>
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackBarStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- snackbar style in res/values -->
<style name="MySnackBarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/mySnackbarBackgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

and provide your colors in your `values/colors.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="myColorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="myColorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="myColorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="mySnackbarBackgroundColor">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

**UPDATE 2020**

As the above solution removes the round corner of the snacker bacause setting the background this way uses the legacy snackbar design, if you want to preserve the material design you can.

1. If you are targeting API 21+

replace `android:background` with `android:backgroundTint`

```xml
<!-- snackbar style in res/values-21/ -->
<style name="MySnackBarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/mySnackbarBackgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

2. If you are targeting API < 21 then if you decide to use legacy snackbar for API < 21 you could set your abouve `MySnackbarStyle` in **res/values-21/** folder and leave the previous — legacy — style in your **res/values** folder.
3. If you are targeting API < 21 and you want to have the material style of the snackbar also in this lower API levels you can change your snackbar style in your **res/values/** this way:

```xml
<!-- snackbar style in res/values/ -->
<style name="MySnackBarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_snackbar_background</item>
</style>
```

and borrow your `my_snackbar_background` from the [official repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/material-components/material-components-android/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/res/drawable/design_snackbar_background.xml), this way:

```xml
<!-- in res/drawable/ -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/mySnackbarBackgroundColor"/>
</shape>
```

**EDIT 2022:**

If you only want to change a single snackbar, and not across the app, then you can use a ContextThemeWrapper as following;

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomSnackbarTheme);
customSnackBar = Snackbar.make(ctw, view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

and in your style file

```
<style name="CustomSnackbarTheme">
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MySnackBarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

Here is a [playground repo](https://github.com/shadowsheep1/android-snackbar-theming).

[image]

Comment: This is the cleanest and best solution

Comment: It's change the size of the snakbar

Comment: Note that your AppTheme must inherits from Theme.MaterialComponents to compile

Comment: Thanks for `my_snackbar_background`. Without it Snackbar drew with rounder corners.

Comment: I added a bit more styling in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62006413/2914140.

Comment: Note that the action button text has an alpha by default. If you don't want this, you can set `actionTextColorAlpha` in `MySnackBarStyle` to 1.

Comment: this is the best solution

Answer (score 25):

**Kotlin version (with an [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)) :**

Create in a file (for exemple SnackbarExtension.kt) an extension :

```
fun Snackbar.withColor(@ColorInt colorInt: Int): Snackbar{
   this.view.setBackgroundColor(colorInt)
   return this
}
```

Next, in your Activity/Fragment, you'll be able to do this :

```
Snackbar
  .make(coordinatorLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .withColor(YOUR_COLOR)
  .show()
```

Comment: Really like this answer, I added the text colouring as well:

    fun Snackbar.withColor(@ColorInt backgroundColor: Int, @ColorInt textColor: Int) : Snackbar {
      this.view.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor)
      this.view.findViewById<TextView>(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text).setTextColor(textColor)
      return this
    }

Answer (score 21):

If you want to define a background color for all your Snackbars, just override the `design_snackbar_background_color` value somewhere in your resources. For example:

```
<color name="design_snackbar_background_color" tools:override="true">@color/colorPrimaryLight</color>
```

Comment: This solution is cleanest and nice. Thanks!

Comment: Works great, just stick this in colors.xml and you are set!

Comment: Nope. Didn't work for me. Neither did any of the other solutions.

Answer (score 18):

With the [**Material Components Library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) just use the [**`setBackgroundTint`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#setbackgroundtint) method.

```
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Snackbar custom style", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.secondaryColor));
    snackbar.show();
```

[image]

---

With **Jetpack Compose** you can customize the [**`SnackbarHost`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#SnackbarHost(androidx.compose.material.SnackbarHostState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)) defining a custom `Snackbar`

```
    snackbarHost = {
        // reuse default SnackbarHost to have default animation and timing handling
        SnackbarHost(it) { data ->
            Snackbar(
                snackbarData = data,
                backgroundColor = Color.Red
            )
        }
    },
```

Then just use it:

```
scope.launch {scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Snackbar text")}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

**Bellow code is useful for change the text color of message.**

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Enter Your Message",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
View view = snackbar.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
snackbar.show();
```

*Second Way: You can change color by changing theme of activity also.*

Answer (score 7):

It's too late but In case someone still needs help. Here is the working solution.

```
      Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainView, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.btn_background_color));
    snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a little utils class so I can easily make custom colored snackbars thru out the app.

```
package com.yourapppackage.yourapp;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SnackbarUtils {

    private int BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    private int TEXT_COLOR;
    private int BUTTON_COLOR;
    private String TEXT;


    public SnackbarUtils(String aText, int aBgColor, int aTextColor, int aButtonColor){
        this.TEXT = aText;
        this.BACKGROUND_COLOR = aBgColor;
        this.TEXT_COLOR = aTextColor;
        this.BUTTON_COLOR = aButtonColor;
    }

    public Snackbar snackieBar(){
        Snackbar snackie = Snackbar.make(MainActivity.getInstance().findViewById(android.R.id.content), TEXT, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View snackView = snackie.getView();
        TextView snackViewText = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        Button snackViewButton = (Button) snackView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);
        snackView.setBackgroundColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        snackViewText.setTextColor(TEXT_COLOR);
        snackViewButton.setTextColor(BUTTON_COLOR);
        return snackie;
    }
}
```

then to use it, like this any where in the app:

```
new SnackbarUtils("This is the text displayed", Color.RED, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW).snackieBar().setAction("OTAY", v -> { 
     //donothing
     }).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

While Working with xamarin android I found out that ContextCompat.GetColor() returns Int but the setBackgroundColor() expects a Parameter of type Color.
So here is how I got it working in my xamarin android project.

```
Snackbar snackbarview =  Snackbar.Make(toolbar, message, Snackbar.LengthLong);
View snckView = snackbarview.View;                
snckView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(GetString(Resource.Color.colorPrimary)));
snackbarview.Show();
```

Comment: +1 for Xamarin `View snckView = snackbarview.View;` instead of `snackbar.getView();` which is not available but `ParseColor` is not working.

Comment: @Cfun Can you explain your problem a bit more, so that i can help you with it.

Comment: My bad I used `System.Drawing.Color.ParseColor` instead of `Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor`. now I have: "the name 'getstring' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Cfun Are you getting this error in an activity or a fragment or you are calling the getString() in some other class?

Comment: I am calling it in some other Class.

Comment: @Cfun then make sure you are also passing the fragment's context or activity context or you can also try application context to to your other class and then do

    context.getString()    
    
it should work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219914/discussion-between-satyajeet-ranjan-and-cfun).

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin:

```
Snackbar.make(view,"simple text",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setBackgroundTint(Color.RED).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it in an Utility class:

```
public class Utility {
    public static void showSnackBar(Context context, View view, String text) {
        Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        sb.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
        sb.show();
    }
}
```

Using like this:

```
Utility.showSnackBar(getApplicationContext(), findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Add success!!!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Old format using Java

```
mySnackbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.black));
```

Actualy format using kt

```
mySnackbar.setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, android.R.color.black));
```

Answer (score 1):

None of other solutions really worked for me. If I only set Snackbar's background color, the layout under TextView and Button was in default color. If I set TextView's background it did a little blink after SnackBar was shown. And layout around button was still in default color.

At the end I found out that the best way for me is to change background color of TextView's parent (SnackbarContentLayout). Now whole Snackbar is colored properly and it doesn't blink when it shows up.

```
snack = Snackbar.make(view, text, duration)
View view = snack.getView();
view.setBackgroundColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
TextView tv = view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(TEXT_COLOR);
((SnackbarContentLayout) tv.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setBackgroundResource()` works just as well.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
sbView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);
snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the solutions that were provided have one disadvantage.
They change the shape of snackbar and remove the radius.

Personally, prefer something like that

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
val view = snackbar.getView();
val color = view.resources.getColor(colorId)
view.background.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Comment: @KishanSolanki You can use the [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)) instead

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why setBackgroundColor() didn't find in my project. That's why I created an extension function and it's fine now.

```
fun View.showSnackBar(message: String) {
    val snackBar = Snackbar.make(this, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    snackBar.setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, R.color.colorAccent))
    snackBar.show()
}
```

and call it like bellow

`activity_login.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_holder_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   // your UI

</FrameLayout>
```

`LoginActivity.kt`

```
login_holder_layout.showSnackBar("Invalid Email")
```

Answer (score 1):

### July 2023 : Kotin Working Code Example

[image]

```
private fun showSnackBar(message: String) {
    rootView?.let {
        val snackBar = Snackbar.make(it, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).apply {
            setAction("Reload") {}
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(it.context, R.color.yellow))
            show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomBar {

public static void show(View view, String message, boolean isLong) {
    Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(view, message, isLong ? Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG : Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    s.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(), R.color.red_900));
    s.show();
}

public static void show(View view, @StringRes int message, boolean isLong) {
    Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(view, message, isLong ? Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG : Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    s.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(), R.color.red_900));
    s.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you use Material 3 Theme

```
<style name="ApplicationTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/SnackbarStyle</item>
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/SnackbarTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SnackbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="SnackbarTextViewStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

> ### you can use this code on the material design library

you can use the way

### create color code

open the res/values/colors.xml and add this line

```
<resources>
    <color name="custom_color_name">CustomCode</color>
</resources>
```

### create Snackbar and change Background

open your activity or fragment and create Snackber

```
Snackbar snackbar= Snackbar.make(root,R.string.imageUploadTitle_error, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

### get Snackbar View

now you should get the SnackbarView and Change custom background in it

```
View snackview = snackbar.getView();
```

### change background color

set the snackbar background color with this function

```
snackview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity() , R.color.error));
```

### showing this snackbar

now should show the Snackbar

```
snackbar.show();
```

### so you can see changed background to custom color

Comment: what's new in your answer other than the given solutions?