# Resources$NotFoundException while trying to change color

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to change color of my snackbar

```
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, Color.RED));
```

I am getting something like this :

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffff0000
```

Where definitely

> ## 0xffff0000
>
> represents RED.But why it cant find this resource?
>   Any help?

Comment: `Color.RED` is an actual color value, not a resource name. If you want `Color.RED`, just use it directly - `setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)`.

Comment: Done,Thanks @MikeM.
Actually I was confused because they raised an issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020891/how-to-change-background-color-of-the-snackbar

Comment: Anything that starts with `R.color` is a resource name for a color resource in your project, and for those you would use `ContextCompat.getColor()` to get the actual value. The `Color` class, however, has several constants - e.g., `Color.RED`, `Color.BLUE`, etc. - that are actual color values. You don't need to pull those from your resources.

Comment: @TuhinSubhra try my answer , it is working properly ..:)

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari,True that,Its working.Thanks.

Comment: @TuhinSubhra your welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :-

In your values.xml , create colors.xml and add following line :

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

Then call this color like this :-

```
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 6):

use: `snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

not: `snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, Color.RED));`

**Reason:**

Look at the [official android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)). 
[image: it says that it need a color id.]

So, you can directly add a color to it. No need to add ContextCompat.getColor() method to it.

If you want to use this, please use a valid ***resource id, not color id*** as the second parameter of the getColor method.
Because from [official website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)) it says,

[image]

it needs resource id, not color id.
Hope, now, you can understand this matter.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43248434/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: Thanks. I will provide it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

> Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffff0000

**This exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found.**

Create custom **`colors.xml`** which holds colors .

**res/values/colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <color name="red">#ff0000 </color>
 
</resources>
```

**Then**

```
setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red));
```

**Or Simple**

```
 setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting background color like this:

```
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.RED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Color.RED is a color not an ID. You should do this:

snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Answer (score 0):

You treat Color.RED(an int value) as a resourceId. Logical mistake!
just use Color.RED insted.
`snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)`