# Is there a way to remove/transparent background color of a snackbar in android?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone guide me how to make background of a snackbar transparent?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020891/how-to-change-background-color-of-the-snackbar

Answer (score 2):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainView, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
snackbar.show();
```

you can define your color as transparent in values.

Comment: Tried this but no success. I picked the default android snackbar which is grey in color. I am able to add or change colors on it but unable to remove the background or make it transparent.

Comment: snackBarView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.trans);                                 
 Where trans → <color name="trans">#00000000 </color>.

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers (Kotlin)

```
snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

It will remove the background from Snackbar